# Show scrollable Image in webview problem

Tags: android, html

I am unable to get default zoom buttons on webview when application runs.

```
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
WebSettings mWebSettings = browser.getSettings();
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

.

```
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webkit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
```

how can I solve these problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For image problem:**

You need to put the images also in asset folder, if you haven't placed them already.

**For inbuilt zoom:**

```
WebSettings mWebSettings = browser.getSettings();
mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: I have added both images and my html file in asset folder already, but its the problem of fix body background.